# Aligning\snapping something to the world\global axis?

Tags: constraints, snapping, axis

In Blender, is there any way of automatically aligning something to the global axis, automatically snapping it to it, or restricting movement to it?

I'm looking for something that's the equivalent of the orthogonal mode in Autocad.

For example, I'd like to grab the rotation handle on the image below and constrain its movement in such as way that it would automatically snap to 0 degrees on the Z axis, so that it was facing straight up. And then be able to grab the vertex below it and have it snap to the same axis.

[image: showing the two vertices]

Answer (score 0):

Blender has a snapping tool if that helps? Click the magnet, and by default it is set to incremental, which will snap whatever you're moving to the grid

[image]

You can then set it to affect the rotation:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

for rotation specifically, try holding control (on a Mac) or control alt or shift on pc to lock to 5 degrees step angle. As of 2.79 the step angle was an option in preferences but couldn't find it in 2.93.